# Different selection behaviours between graphic and console Emacs (23)

Tags: emacs, console, selection, shift

Emacs n00b here, I've fiddled a bit with it in graphical mode and so far I've found it great. I wanted to give the terminal version a try and found out that there's a few annoying behaviour differences, in particular with shift-selection.

In graphical mode I can combine shift selection (ie holding shift to set a mark) with the arrow keys, the control key (to select whole words) or the origin or end keys (to select the whole/a large part of a line).

In terminal mode the keys work fine on their own (I can select regions while holding shift and moving with the arrow keys*, C-left/right allows me to jump whole words, origin and end bring me where I want to go) but I can't combine them (can't select whole words by holding shift and C-arrowing, or select the remaining part of a line with shift-end or shift-origin).

I also found that C-backspace didn't work (ie didn't erase the whole word) in console while it does in window mode, though I read about M-backspace after looking for a solution.

I searched as thoroughly as I could but could not find how to get the terminal version to behave like the graphical version... Lots of people seem to ask questions about Emacs's shift selection but none of them have quite the same problem... Can someone explain where those behaviour differences come from?

Thanks in advance.

*Though, holding shift, if I go down (with the arrow key) to select whole lines, I can't go up again to unselect them (" is undefined").

[edit /] Okay, so obviously this comes from the fact that my terminal doesn't have the same shortcuts as graphical Emacs does. Fair enough. I see a couple of solutions here:

- getting used to default Emacs shortcuts
- filling my .emacs with global-set-key's. Although I tried 

  `(fset 'select-to-end
  [(kbd "C-<spc> <end>")])
  (global-set-key (kbd "S-<end>") 'select-to-end)`

  but it doesn't work as I intend it to -_-

Comment: You're likely running afoul of bad terminal/termcap settings. What OS are you on, and what's `$TERM`?

Comment: My OS is Crunchbang Statler (Debian-based), and $TERM is xterm. I just figured out that actually, since I'm running Emacs in console, the problem's simply that my console doesn't have the same shortcuts for moving around in text... I just found out that I can also move to the beginning/end of the line with C-a/C-e, and select until the beginning/end of the buffer holding shift with M-a/M-e. Now I just need to select until the beginning/end of the line... And (hold shift) C-a/C-e doesn't work (C-s-e is bound to split vertically in my terminal, and C-s-a just doesn't do anything visible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "if you're happy using different keystrokes, that might be easier". Personally, I'm a little neurotic about my keybindings and configuration, so I rarely go with this one; in particular, it's frustrating when emacs modes override your bindings. (I don't know if you've yet discovered that `global-set-key` really means "let anyone in the universe stamp on my keybinding".)

The longer answer to your question is "someone along the chain is ignoring your control characters, so you need to figure out who it is, fix it, and then repeat". For the keybindings you're talking about here -- `C-S-<arrows>` -- you can definitely get this to work; if you want something like `\C-~`, you're going to have a *much* harder time. (The issue is that some bindings didn't make sense in legacy terminals, so you basically have to use a nonstandard set of control codes to transmit the key combination, and then teach each program to recognize it. This is usually where a termcap comes in, since it's a common language for teaching programs about key events.)

Here are the steps I usually take:

- Start with your terminal. You can use `\C-v` and then hit a key to insert the literal keystroke (at least in bash) -- start by doing this with C-left, S-left, and C-S-left. Confirm that you're getting three different control codes.
- If you're not, you need to investigate either (1) your readline settings, (2) your terminal program settings or (3) your termcap settings. Since `TERM` is `xterm`, the termcap *should* be fine. I don't know what terminal program you're using, but it may have its own key configuration. (For instance, I use a mac and use iTerm2, which is usually my first stop.) If you're going to be spending time at a terminal anyway, you should definitely take the time to read the [readline manual](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) and play with your `.inputrc` a bit.
- This chain is short: next is emacs. You can use `\C-q` in emacs to do the same thing `\C-v` does in bash, or use `\C-h k` to find out what the default bindings are. Again, start by making sure emacs sees distinct key events for the combinations you're interested in. If not, you'll probably want to start by looking at `term/xterm.el` in your `site-lisp` directory and modifying it to your liking.

If you're using `tmux` or `screen`, they also get a hand in this, and can usually be tamed. The process for finding those problems is the same as bash -- use `\C-v` and `man tmux` to figure out how to get your extra keybindings.

Comment: C-v'ing arrow, C-arrow and S-arrow gives different results, but C-S-arrow gives none at all. I have no answer from the terminal until I type something else...
C-v'ing home and C-home yield the same result. S-home does not provoke any reaction (resp. end, C-end and S-end).

I had a look at .inputrc and the settings for Terminator (my terminal program), played a bit with them but could not get anything out of that.

That whole "no reaction from C-v" bugs me. I tried to look it up but could not find a similar problem.

... I'm not ruling out the option of settling for your short answer yet >_>

Comment: Two thoughts: (1) Does terminator have an option to add new keybindings? If so, you want c-s-arrows to be `\e[1;6_` or `^[[1;6_` where `_` is `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D` as appropriate. (2) Can you try the same thing in just an xterm (open a terminal and type `xterm &`) to see if maybe your window manager is eating some of the keystrokes?

Comment: (1) I'm looking into that. Changing existing ones seems easy enough but the doc isn't so clear on how to add new bindings - if it is possible at all.

(2) Mmm, xterm clearly shows different codes for each of the combinations I tried in my previous comment - even those which would not get me any feedback on terminator. So it would be a problem with my window manager? Adding new bindings seems to be doable with Openbox, so I'll try that and let you know the results.

Comment: (Ow I can't believe I didn't provide any feedback after two months... Sorry -_-)

I settled for the short answer, although I did try to find the cause of my issues... Can't remember exactly what I found (although terminator doesn't support the addition of shortcuts).

If I ever have some time I'll try to get to the root of all that and post the info here.